# How to realize Singleton pattern with Generics for TForm descendants?

Tags: delphi, generics, design-patterns, singleton, delphi-2010

I want to realize Singleton pattern in Delphi 2010 using Generics feature.

```
type
  TgrsObj = class
     class function Singleton<T: class, constructor>(O: T): T; static;
  end;


class function TgrsObj.Singleton<T>(O: T): T;
begin
   if O = nil then
     O := T.Create;
   Result := O;
end;
```

I would like to call it like:

```
var
  test: TTestClass;

...
test := TgrsObj<TTestClass>(test);
```

Is my approach possible? What should I correct to make it working?

Honestly my final task is to realize Singleton pattern with TForm descendant to have needed forms as singletons.

It is next step but now I have question about CONSTRUCTOR constraint of Generics. It requires a class to have a constructor without parameters. But TForm has not it... What is workaround?

Comment: Singleton is the worst design pattern ever, just saying.

Comment: @Stefan I'm not so sure this would qualify as a true Singleton pattern because nothing prevents creating a additional instances via `Form2 := TMyForm.Create(nil);`. This seems more like a factory where you can go to get a "default instance" that's created on demand. As such, it's not so bad.

Comment: @Craig Agreed. Since O is passed it looks more like some weird kind of static factory. Still a code smell imho because in the end you achieve nothing with it - factories usually are to decouple dependencies but in this case you still have a direct hardcoded dependency as you need to specify T as the type that is being constructed. I would even say this is WTF code because it just disguises a constructor call in an overengineered way using generics.

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, I think you are right... it is like Factory more as Singleton. Could you offer me alternative way to compact and clear code to create a forms. I use noe very simple way. My new code with generics is more compact... It is little bit less readable as my old way. So what is better? Old way: var
  _frmAccessTest: TfrmAccessTest;

function frmAccessTest: TfrmAccessTest;
begin
  if _frmAccessTest = nil then
    _frmAccessTest := TfrmAccessTest.Create(nil);
  Result := _frmAccessTest;
end;

Comment: I would not use the global form variables at all because they just lead to code smells (accessing components on form1 from deep inside form2 and such)

Comment: @Stefan could you show me a way? Maybe a link to any guru blog... How should I use my forms in my apps? If they have interfaces then I could use Spring4d but they have not.

Comment: I would suggest watching this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI&t=1s Also using Spring4d does not magically make good code. It is rather a tool once you applying certain coding principles and architecture in your code.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks! It is clear with simple parameters or even with some classes: do not use global but pass the parameters (to inject). But for example I have form1 and I have to call form2.ShowModal from form1. What is the best way for the form1 to know about the form2? Should I pass the form2 instance as constructor parameter of the form1? In this case I see unit coupling too because I need to include form2's unit in the uses section of the form1 unit. What is the solution for multiforms projects?

Comment: A clear "it depends" :) But let's say you just need to call ShowModal. There is no reason to know about what exact class your form is as this method is available on a TForm. So you can pass it as TForm easily (either as constructor injection or property injection). This also serves the information hiding because you pass an abstraction (a TForm) and not some concrete implementation (TForm2).

Comment: What is about a situation when form1 have to set form2.label2.caption := 'aaa'; ? Observer pattern? Is it too high price for this decoupling... no?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52573/discussion-between-stefan-glienke-and-mad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `constructor` constraint in Delphi is pretty much useless in my opinion. And it is of no real use to you since you need to create `TForm` descendants and they have a constructor that receives a parameter.

You should constrain your generic type `T` to derive from `TForm`.

```
type
  TgrsObj = class
    class function Singleton<T: TForm>(O: T): T; static;
  end;
```

The implementation would then be:

```
class function TgrsObj.Singleton<T>(O: T): T;
begin
   Result := O;
   if not Assigned(Result) then
     Result := T(TFormClass(T).Create(nil));
end;
```

And since you are really just trying to access the virtual `TComponent` constructor you could make the class more general like this:

```
type
  TgrsObj = class
    class function Singleton<T: TComponent>(O: T): T; static;
  end;

class function TgrsObj.Singleton<T>(O: T): T;
begin
   Result := O;
   if not Assigned(Result) then
     Result := T(TComponentClass(T).Create(nil));
end;
```

Of course, this forces `nil` as the owner of the form instance. You will probably want to change the method to receive an owner which can then be passed to the constructor.

Comment: The constructor constraint in Delphi is useless because it does not work. It falls back to TObject.Create if your class is hiding the parameterless constructor. This has already been reported some while ago.

Comment: @David Thanks a lot. Works so.

Comment: @Stefan It's also useless when the constructor has parameters which is exceedingly common.

Comment: Because that is not what it is for. It is for restricting to classes that have a parameterless constructor to be able to create them inside the generic class because the solution as you showed only works with virtual constructors. For everything else the factory pattern is your friend. Also the problem is that the compiler does not allow to call T.Create(AComponent) although you have a constraint on T to only allow TComponent.

Comment: @Stefan I understand what it is for. I just think it is useless. I find the code in my answer equally poor. All that casting!